# How to get Alphabet from the given integer value?

Tags: java

How to get alphabets by the numeric postion in java ?

Suppose i have entered 1 then as a output i need to get A how can i get the alphabets position in java?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 66 - 1 = 65 ==> numeric value of char A

Comment: Most Java collections and arrays are 0 based. Wouldn't 1 give you actually 'B'?

Comment: The solution could be from an array or the ascii value of the character. It's up to you (or your homework) how you should solve the problem.

Comment: Agrees with @Luiggi. You shouldn't be posting this sort of question without also showing your attempt.

Comment: dont thank, vote and accept please - http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```
int i = 1;
System.out.println((char)(i+'A'-1));
```

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels OP accepted the answer so why -1 everybody used that?

Answer (score 2):

```
int charValue = 1; //this is the number you enter
char letter = (char)(charValue+64);  //this is the character you want
```

For lowercase letters, use (charValue+96)

Comment: I'd prefer to use `charValue + 'A'` instead, is easier to remember.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [switch/case statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) to manually get each letter however a better solution would be to use the ASCII table to get the letters.

ASCII Table: http://www.ascii-code.com/

```
public char getLetter(int i)
{
  return (char) (i + 64);
}
```

The above function would return 'A' when i is 1

Comment: Got my languages mixed up :P Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You have letters/characters, think of them as positions in an array.

```
int number = 0;
String[] array = new String[] {"a", "b", "c", "..."};
String letter = array[number + 1];
```

Comment: +1: This is a very good idea if the characters in your language are different from English lang i.e. Spanish that handles the ñ and Ñ